# Automatic DNS not work in my Laptop

Tags: dns

I am facing an unknown problem in my laptop. i AM Using a router. From same router I connect my another PC and mobiles using same Wi-Fi. But my laptop not found internet. I have to use Manual DNS 4.2.2.1 . If I use this DNS then I can access internet. But all other my device and PC connect internet without problem. how to solve my Laptop problem. I am am using windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to connect by Ethernet the notebook to the router?, to discard an OS problem.

The other option that you can try is deleting the WiFi config of that network.

Check if you have dhcp activated and check in your notebook if the ip is checked in automatic. Could happen that if you have manual ip, your dhcp is not in the range of your ip

Answer (score 0):

DNS Doesn't connect you to the internet.

### [DNS Explained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7WrY.gif)

It's possible you disabled DHCP in your router :P

You won't get a IP if that's the case

Please go to CMD.exe and type

> ipconfig /all

Please post the following information:

> - DHCP Enabled
> - IPv4 Address
> - Subnet Mask
> - Default Gateway
> - DHCP Server
> - DNS Servers

Easy fix: Press the reset button on your router

> If Only your Laptop faces this problem disable STATIC IP
>
> ### Explained

1. Right click your network adapter
2. Choose "Change adapter settings"
3. Richt click your connected network adapter
4. Select "Properties"
5. Click on "Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)
6. Choose Properties
7. Select "Obtain an IP address automatically"
8. Select "Obtain DNS Server address automatically"
9. Click "OK" then "Close"
10. Done.